# How Can I Disable Authentication in Django REST Framework

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a store site, where every user is going to be anonymous (well, until it's time to pay at least), and I'm trying to use Django REST Framework to serve the product API, but it keeps complaining about:

```
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

I found some settings related to authentication, but I couldn't find anything like `ENABLE_AUTHENTICATION = True`. How do I simply disable authentication, and let any visitor to the site access the API?

Comment: Related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970970/django-rest-framework-permission-classes-of-viewset-method

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You can give empty defaults for the [permission](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions#setting-the-permission-policy) and [authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#setting-the-authentication-scheme) classes in your settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # other settings...

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
}
```

Comment: how can i skip authentication for only one class in DRF

Comment: @roanjain add the attribute `authentication_classes = []` - the settings dict is, as its name suggests, merely a default.

Comment: @OllieFord That sounds like a recipe for disaster. If someone sets the default auth to none, and later another person forgets to specify any auth class for any endpoint, that endpoint will be potentially unprotected. I would like to stay with the "blacklisting" practice instead of a "whitelisting" and just specify a magic anonymous authentication and permission classes to the particular endpoint I want to leave open.

Comment: @CsabaToth I don't understand how my above comment isn't what you want? Leave `'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES' = ['YourAuthenticationClass']` in settings, and put `authentication_classes = []` on the the view that you want to leave open. If this attribute is not supplied, the default from settings will be used - no disaster here.

Comment: @OllieFord It's difference between whitelisting and blacklisting from security perspective. Night and day. Read my comment again. BTW I could go without authentication by not disabling the default but assigning `[]` to the particular endpoint.

Comment: @CsabaToth I think you must be misreading my suggestion - I am *not* saying disable auth in settings, I am saying override it on the specific endpoint you want accessible without auth. I agree the alternative (no default in settings, specifying on every view) is a nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: Dealing with this issue was an absolute nightmare for me on an existing project -- I had to also make a tweak to the `UNAUTHENTICATED_USER` DRF setting (going off this [old, but helpful comment](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/3262#issuecomment-147541598)). In my case, setting this to `None` didn't work so I wrote a `User` class with no methods, and just `is_authenticated = True` as a class attribute. Not sure why, but seemed like `csrf` was for some reason triggering the auth check ...

Answer (score 77):

You can also disable authentication for particular class or method, just keep blank the decorators for the particular method.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes, permission_classes

@authentication_classes([])
@permission_classes([])
@api_view(['POST']) 
def items(request):
   return Response({"message":"Hello world!"})
```

Comment: Is there anyone which has succesfully implement this snippet? I tried and not working.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970970/django-rest-framework-permission-classes-of-viewset-method

Comment: Yes it working fine in my case, I have used this with user registration viewset, can you please tell me what error you are getting?

Comment: This will only work if you use the `@api_view` decorator: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#setting-the-authentication-scheme

Comment: in some drf versions the decorator orders is very important. for me this order is working:
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([])
@permission_classes([])

Answer (score 34):

if you want to disable authentication for a certain class based view, then you can use,

```
class PublicEndPoint(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [] #disables authentication
    permission_classes = [] #disables permission
    
    def get(self, request):
        pass
```

This is useful when you want to make only specific endpoints available public.

Comment: This is the way to go. Thank you!

Comment: what if you want to disable on a specific endpoint inside the same `APIView` class? Such as `get`, but not on `post`?

Comment: @Bersan the simplest way is to make your view public and check permission inside the post method.

Comment: @Sumithran how?

Comment: I had to use permissions.AllowAny  as it did not disable anything

Comment: This answer saved my day!

Answer (score 11):

You can also apply it on one specific endpoint by applying it on class or method. Just need to apply **django rest framework AllowAny permission** to the specific method or class.

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

from .serializers import CategorySerializer
from catalogue.models import Category   

@permission_classes((AllowAny, ))
class CategoryList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.CategorySerializer
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
```

You can achieve the same result by using an empty list or tuple for the permissions setting, but you may find it useful to specify this class because it makes the intention explicit.

Answer (score 9):

To enable authentication globally add this to your django settings file:

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
),
'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
),
```

then add the following decorators to your methods to enable unauthenticated access to it

```
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes, permission_classes

@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes([])
@permission_classes([])
def register(request):
  try:
    username = request.data['username']
    email = request.data['email']
    password = request.data['password']
    User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
    return Response({ 'result': 'ok' })
  except Exception as e:
    raise APIException(e)
```

Answer (score 7):

If using APIView you can create a permission for the view, example below:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^my-endpoint', views.MyEndpoint.as_view())
```

**permissions.py**

```
class PublicEndpoint(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True
```

**views.py**

```
from permissions import PublicEndpoint

class MyEndpoint(APIView):

    permission_classes = (PublicEndpoint,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        return Response({'Info':'Public Endpoint'})
```

Comment: your PublicEndpoint implementation is the same as rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny

Comment: @MikePlacentra Yes, this whole answer can be replaced by  from rest_framework.permissions import  AllowAny  & permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

Comment: That looks very promising, and best of all, it's easy to understand! Unfortunately, when I use it in my codebase, I still get 403 FORBIDDEN. I put a logging statement in the `PublicEndpoint` and that log statement is not hit which means my permission_class isn't being consulted at all. :sigh:

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative to simply enable the API forms for development purposes:

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
    ]
}
```

*Django REST framework v3.11.0*

Answer (score 3):

For **class view** you can do:

```py
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        content = {
            'status': 'request was permitted'
        }
        return Response(content)
```

For **function view** you can do:

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def example_view(request, format=None):
    content = {
        'status': 'request was permitted'
    }
    return Response(content)
```

More details at [Setting the permission policy](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy)

Answer (score 1):

Also, it can be the separate class for the dev.

```
class DevAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        return models.User.objects.first(), None
```

And in settings.py:

```
DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES = ["common.authentication.DevAuthentication"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#in settings.py

    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
        'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        ),
        'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
        ),
        'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
       'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ]
    
    }



class ListView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    def get(self,request):
        customers = Customer.objects.filter(is_superuser=False)
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(customers, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: It looks like you're setting `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` twice, so it's confusing what the intent is. If you just want `AllowAny` you can omit the first instance of `IsAuthenticated` entirely. Or if you want both, include them in the same tuple/list.