# Limit access api view decorator Django through post method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, restful-authentication

I have a user group created which name is "Experts" and I have the Django's rest_framework installed too. I can access through api to my items and the comments of all items. Well, I should limit the post action through api to comments. This action just will be available to Experts' users. I have the following code at my views.py (I am just posting the important code):

```
from .serializers import FeedbackSerializer
class FeedbackViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
            """
            API endpoint that allows Items to be viewed or edited.
            """
            queryset = Feedback.objects.all().order_by('user')
            serializer_class = FeedbackSerializer
            def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
               self.permission_classes = ['IsAdminUser',]
               return super(FeedbackViewSet, self).create(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I was checking the official documentation about the restful api but I don't understand how I can override with `(@api_view('POST'),@permission_classes((IsAdminUser, )))` the method called through api to display all comments

Comment: ViewSets have multiple actions, you should override the one you need: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets Maybe it would be easier for you to just make a single POST endpoint, not declare heaps of un-needed ViewSet code.

Comment: Uhm, but should I write the create method of FeedbackViewSet inside this class? Or is there any way that I can override it? Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm newbie in Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyViewset(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyThing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyThingSerializer

    def update(self, request, pk=None, **kwargs):
        self.permission_classes = [CustomPermission,]

        return super(MyViewset, self).update(request, pk, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I inserted your code into my class and replace "CustomPermission" with "IsAdminUser" due to that I want allow the post when the user belongs to staff. The comments are display properly but if I try to add a Feedback through api with a non staff member, the feedback is added

Comment: You can override the create method as well:
`def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):`

Comment: Okay, I updated my code here too. But now when I try to post a new Feedback I got the following error: `AttributeError at /api/comments/ 'FeedbackViewSet' object has no attribute 'data'`

Comment: Maybe this solution is better? Sorry I can't actually test any code atm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970970/django-rest-framework-permission-classes-of-viewset-method

Comment: Thanks your sir, it was my fault. I forgot import isadminuser from permissions and now it is working. Thanks for your help!