# Passwordless User authentication with a Django or just any REST API system

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, restful-authentication

I am implementing a webservice with a bunch of REST API. These REST API will all be invoked from a python command line interface script.

When a userA, logged in as himself on a unix system, invokes that CLI python script, I would like the script to be able to invoke the REST API through the python HTTP client, but do it without having to use a password.

Since he is already, authenticated as himself on the linux.

How can this be implemented? 
Are there any Django packages/documentation that help with it?

Comment: If you want to disable authentication sitewide, use this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27086121/2131133)

Comment: You are going to need some sort of authentication to make sure it is your unix systems accessing the API. You could potentially use a locked private key or (if you aren't worried too much about security) just put the password in your script or environment variables.

Comment: Jonathan, I was hoping there is a standard process to authenticate with web services when on a mutually trusted linux machine. Right now, if I don't here any existing solution, my plan is to do the following. signin using userid and password once from the client, and when done establish a shared secutiry token between the user, stored in his home directory and the webserver, and use that for authentication.

Comment: Nagkumar, thats not what I am trying to do