# Django Rest Framework - authentication_classes by method in viewsets

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I want to disable authentication on creation in my `UserViewSet`, so that even non authenticated user can create an account.

I'm using `django-oauth-toolkit` to authenticate in my application, and I use their authentication class as default in my settings (which is great)

I have tried to use the `@authentication_class` decorator (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39717881/5438372), but it doesn't seem to work with `ModelViewSet`

And I also tried to override the `get_authenticator` method, in the same spirit as this : [Django rest framework permission_classes of ViewSet method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970970/django-rest-framework-permission-classes-of-viewset-method), but `ViewSet.action` doesn't seem to be available at authentication.

How can I do this ? I there something wrong with my approach ?

Here is my code :

```
<models.py:>
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsSelfOrStaffPermission, TokenHasReadWriteScope,)
    lookup_field = 'username'

    def get_queryset(self):
        current_user = self.request.user
        if current_user.is_staff:
            user_set = User.objects.all()
        else:
            user_set = User.objects.filter(username=current_user.username)

        query = self.request.query_params.get('q', None)

        if not query:
            return user_set

        return user_set.filter(
            Q(username__icontains=query) |
            Q(first_name__icontains=query) |
            Q(last_name__icontains=query)
        )

<settings.py:>
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
    ),

    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}

<permission.py:>
class IsSelfOrStaffPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Permission to allow user actions on his own profile
    """
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj == request.user or request.user.is_staff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if `view.action` is 'create' or not inside `has_permission` method:

```
class IsSelfOrStaffPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Permission to allow user actions on his own profile
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return view.action == 'create'
```

Comment: I thought the problem couldn't be fixed at permission level, but your answer gave me the idea. The solution was to override the `has_permission` method of `TokenAsReadWriteScope`