# disable django rest framework authentication for special functions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework for authentication.

```
 'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
    ),
```

But in my register function:

```
class UserRegister(APIView):
    @staticmethod
    def post(request, user_name):
.
.
.
.
.
```

obviously I do not need token, however I am getting error:

```
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

I tried this possible answer:
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39717881/8923269)

but I am encountering this error:

```
'staticmethod' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

and by deleting @staticmethod decorator, I am getting the previous error again:

```
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

How to exclude this special function from requiring token?

tnx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to disable authentication completely on any DRF view, you can override the `permission_classes` field.

Your code should look something like :

```
class UserRegister(APIView):

    permission_classes = []

    def post():
```

Comment: does this still work? Doesn't seem to do the trick as I keep getting a 405

Answer (score 2):

I think this might work,

```
class UserRegister(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [] 

    def post(request, user_name):
        # do your stuff
        return Response()
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the option for it

```
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

class ViewName(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        ......
```

Try this....