# Sign in required when accessing gcloud API

Tags: python, django, reactjs, axios, dialogflow-es

I am building an app that uses the dialogflow API, and I am having the following issue, the loading of a url (spectific intent details with training phrases) require my PC user credentials (login and password).

I assume to 99% that it comes from React because when debugging the server side(Django), the login requirement does not even call the server.

Should I look into the package-lock.json file ?

I am bit stuck with this, because this is the only thing remaining before the app deployment?

Thanks

Comment: I could find the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972808/disable-django-rest-framework-authentication-for-special-functions) Hope it could help someone

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not taking the Service Account credentials from the OS environment.

I suggest to create the client directly from the credential file:

```py
client = dialogflow.IntentsClient.from_service_account_file(CREDENTIALS_PATH)
```