# Django Authentication granularity

Tags: django-authentication

Is there a way to reduce the granularity of auth for a specific view?

For example, I only want to check for auth for POST requests and not GET requests.

My current code looks like this: (which requires both GET and POST to provide a jwt)

```
class PartView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JSONWebTokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is quite the correct syntax but it's one way to do it (didn't test it).

Implement your own custom permission that lets through post requests with an authenticated user and get requests with no restriction.

Authentication class returns an `AnonymouseUser` or `None` if not authenticated, but the permission class does the authorization checks.

```
class AllowUnauthenticatedGetRequests(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if (request.method == "GET")
            return True

        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated)
```

Then replace the permission in the view:

```
permission_classes = [AllowUnauthenticatedGetRequests]
```

References

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/
- https://github.com/jpadilla/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/master/rest_framework_jwt/authentication.py
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser
- [How Can I Disable Authentication in Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27085219/how-can-i-disable-authentication-in-django-rest-framework)